# How do I bind onchange event of a TextBox using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I bind an OnChange event of a TextBox to function using jQuery?

Am trying this and its failing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#tags").bind("change",autoFill);
});

function autoFill() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete("/taglookup/", {
        width: 320,
        max: 4,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator:",",
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300,
        delay: 10
    });
}
```

NB: I want to implement a Tag TextBox like the one for stackoverflow which detects OnChange events and calls AJAX functions when a user types in.

Comment: What does exactly fail? Is the autofill not called or is it something else?

Comment: For a textbox with an autocomplete functionality, it's probably better onkeyup event.

Comment: @Eddy, why is that?  Wouldn't you be better off sending the AJAX request of asap?

Answer (score 31):

You're looking for keydown/press/up

```
$("#inputID").keydown(function(event) {
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

or using bind $("#inputID").bind('onkeydown', ...

http://docs.jquery.com/Events

Comment: I found that using `keydown` meant that my handler would fire on certain weird keystrokes such as ALT+TAB.

Comment: Key* only works for keypresses. If you paste something in the textbox using the mouse context menu it won't fire. Using an onchange event is usually the way to go.

Comment: @ingredient_15939 which is why my answer specifically mentions "If you're looking for KEYdown/press/up", not talking about the mouse events

Answer (score 18):

You must change the event name from "change" to "onchange":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#tags").bind("onchange", autoFill);
          });
```

or use the shortcut binder method change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#tags").change(autoFill);
          });
```

Note that the onchange event usually fires when the user leave the input, so for auto-complete you better use the keydown event.

Answer (score 7):

Combination of `keyup` and `change` is not necessarily enough (browser's autocomplete and paste using mouse also changes the contents of a text box, but doesn't fire either of these events):

[jquery change not working incase of dynamic value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035633/jquery-change-not-working-incase-of-dynamic-value-change/4280932#4280932)

Answer (score 1):

I 2nd Chad Grant's answer and also submit this blog article [removed dead link] for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: That link (http://themaingate.net/dev/javascript/jquerys-annoying-edits-to-onchange-behavior) appears to be dead.

Comment: ONOZ. I hate it when that happens. I will remove the link. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clue why an onchange() call might not fire your bound function:

http://jehiah.cz/archive/firing-javascript-events-properly

Answer (score 1):

What Chad says, except its better to use .keyup in this case because with .keydown and .keypress the value of the input is still the older value i.e. the newest key pressed would not be reflected if .val() is called.

This should probably be a comment on Chad's answer but I dont have privileges to comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to use jQuery autocomplete plugin, then I think you don't need to bind to onChange event, it will