# How to catch onchange event on multiple textbox field

Tags: jquery

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="percentage[]" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="percentage[]" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="percentage[]" value="3"/>
```

I want to be able to catch change event by using JQuery when any of the 'percentage' text fields changes and find sum of all these fields. So, if the value on the first field changes from 1 to 5, I want to be able to display "10".

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805963/how-do-i-bind-onchange-event-of-a-textbox-using-jquery/805976#805976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use something like this:

```
$("input[type='text'][name^='percentage']").keyup(function(){
   alert(sumThemUp());
});

function sumThemUp(){
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type='text'][name^='percentage']").each(function(){
        sum+= parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    return sum;
};
```

**Working example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/5VpL2/1/).**

You can also check jQuery API to choose selector that might fit you better if you wish. There are many variations like !=, ~=, *= etc.

Comment: Thank you. This works. But when I tried to implement this by $('input[name=percentage]'), it didn't work. Can't I use name attribute instead of text attribute? What if I have other text fields with different names but I want to sum up only the percentage field?

Comment: Opps! I just saw your answer.

Comment: I modified my answer.. the correct selector is `$("input[type='text'][name^='percentage']")`. This will match all text inputs with name starting with word percentage. Much easier way is imo adding custom css class and then identify the elements by that class.

Comment: Thanks Dampe. It works; and I used CSS class as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have another element to show the sum in, and no other input elements, this will work:

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
        // Clear the sum
        $("#sum").text("0");

        // Sum the values
        $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
                $("#sum").text( parseInt($("#sum").text()) + parseInt($(this).val()))
            });
    });
```

It catches the elements changing, and then loops over all of them and sums them up.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, there are other input fields (like checkboxes). So how I differentiate from other input fields?