# Return a response if string is not found in autocomplete using Materialize Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

how can return like alert message if the input is not matched or is not selected from the autocomplete result. My datasource came from my controller.

Here's my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: site_url('appointment/getPatientName'),
        type: 'get',
        success: function(response){
            data = {};
            $.each(response, function(key, val){
                data[key] = val;
            });
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                data: data,
                limit:5
            });
        },
    });
```

I tried to do this using the input's change event but it is not working because I think it uses li element instead of select element.

Here's my attempt:

```
$('#patient_name').on('change', function(){
 var content = $('.autocomplete-content'); 
    if(content.length === 0){
        alert('none');
    }
});
```

I found what's likely I want to achieved here's the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/x5q6Q/). It's not jquery-ui which has a response callback but materialize don't have.

Comment: The change event doesn't trigger until the input loses focus, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805963/how-do-i-bind-onchange-event-of-a-textbox-using-jquery

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working.